# Right-clicking triggers a sequence of keyboard inputs

Tags: windows-7

I was playing a game earlier and suddenly my character starts moving and shooting on its own. I thought it was just the game acting up but apparently not. Now, every time I right-click (with my mouse, touch pad right-click button doesn't trigger this), a sequence of keyboard inputs starts executing. The sequence is basically my inputs while I was playing (WASD movement .. etc.) and it's always the exact same sequence.

I tried plugging my mouse into another USB port, I unplugged the computer and took out the battery but that didn't help. I also looked at the running processes and didn't find anything suspicious.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be? My OS is Windows 7 and the mouse is a Microsoft Sidewinder which I've had for over 2 years now with no problems.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using AutoHotkey? Does restarting the computer fix it?

Comment: No, I'm not using AutoHotkey. Restarting, shutting down and even taking the battery, hard drive and my RAM out didn't do anything. :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just set up a macro accidentally. If something similar happens to you, just go to your mouse settings and clear it.

Answer (score 0):

Please reinstall mouse drivers